# Making $url from article.php available in Joomla Articles for custom readmore links

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category-blog

I'm trying to make the string `$url` from `article.php`, which contains the link to the full article in Joomla, available to make custom readmore links in my articles.

To be exactly clear: I want to use the code `<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Readmore</a>` in my articles when I edit them in the `Joomla Backend / Content / Articles / Edit Article`.

Maybe somebody has an idea here. I already tried the DirectPHP Plugin but I didn't have any luck with it so far.

Comment: What is article.php? Do you know about template overrides? https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Answer (score 2):

By default, PHP code is stripped from article content when saving.

[DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/directphp) and similar extensions enable you to include PHP code in your articles without the code being stripped by your editor when saving the article.

Remember to enable the plugin in `Extensions -> Plugins`.

If DirectPHP isn't working for you, I suggest trying an alternative such as [Regular Labs Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer).

Remember to enable the plugin in `Extensions -> Plugins` after installation and then add your code to your article like this:

```
{source}
  <?php
    echo $url;
  ?>
{/source}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use JCE Editor and use "read more" link ?

Its free:

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net